# Enabling SSL with Laragon Apache issue

Tags: apache, ssl, laragon

I get 90 days free SSL Certificate from ZeroSSL which contains 3 files: ca_bundle.crt, certificates.crt, and private.key. Then put it into C:\laragon\etc\ssl

Edit C:\laragon\etc\apache2\sites-enabled\00-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile       C:/laragon/etc/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile    C:/laragon/etc/ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile  C:/laragon/etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
    
#SSLCertificateFile      C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.crt
#SSLCertificateKeyFile   C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.key
</VirtualHost>
```

C:\laragon\etc\apache2\httpd-ssl.conf already automatically edited by Laragon

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4

SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
```

C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.47-win64-VS16\conf\httpd.conf also  automatically edited by Laragon

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP Off

IncludeOptional "C:/laragon/etc/apache2/alias/*.conf"
IncludeOptional "C:/laragon/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf"
Include "C:/laragon/etc/apache2/httpd-ssl.conf"
Include "C:/laragon/etc/apache2/mod_php.conf"
```

But SSL works Local only.

It doesn't work when access from internet with error message -

> This site can’t be reached - took too long to respond

.

Where am I doing wrong? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disregard question above.

Found the answer, its because I forgot to turn off firewall on port 443.

Sorry

Answer (score 15):

Activate the SSL Port on: Laragon -> Menu -> Preferences -> Services & Ports

Also you may need to check that you have active openSSL extension on:
Menu -> PHP -> Extensions -> openssl

Also check Menu -> Apache -> SSL -> Add Laragon.crt to TrustStore

RESTART Laragon!

Comment: Also if Nginx is installed then Also check Menu -> Nginx-> SSL -> Add Laragon.crt to TrustStore

Answer (score -1):

Try this steps
Preferences->Services and Port tab then enable ssl 443 port then go
Menu->apache->ssl->add laragon.crt to trust  store